# Find all the users in an organization and it's suborganizations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

A user belongs to an organization, which in turn can have multiple users and child organizations. How do you find all the organizations users?

I have the models named `User` and `Organization`. They have the following relationships:

**In the user model:**

```
belongs_to :organization
```

**In the organization model:**

```
has_many :users
has_many :child_organizations, class_name: "Organization", foreign_key:"parent_id"
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Organization"
```

I want to find all users who belong to `child_organizations` of the current user organization.

```
@users = current_user.organization.child_organizations.users
```

It returns this error:

```
undefined method `users' for Organization::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x8f975d0
```

Comment: You Should edit your Question and Post some sample data as per Model

Answer (score 1):

Based on the formatting of your question I'm not entirely sure what it is you have for you model relationships. But if you want to find all users whom belong to child_organizations of current_user's organization ...

**This is how you can set up your relationships**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :child_organization
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :child_organizations
  has_many :users, through: :child_organizations
end

class ChildOrganization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :users
end
```

And now you can use the following

```
@users = current_user.organization.users
```

Comment: Thanks, it means that I need another modal that store the child_organization user.